# Elementary number theory exponent problem (Peter Hackman book)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $a$,$b$ be positive integers satisfying $a^j$ = $b^k$ for positive and relatively prime integers j,k.

Show that a = $r^k$, b = $r^j$ for some positive integer r.

Can you help me to figure it out ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try
to make use of this:

Since
$j$ and $k$
are relatively prime,
there are integers
$u$ and $v$
such that
$uj-vk = 1$.

After some experimentation,
this looks promising:

If
$a^j = b^k$,
then
$a^{uvj} = b^{uvk}$.

We will need the result that
if a rational number
raised to an integer power
is an integer,
then the rational number
must be an integer.

$b^{uvk}
=a^{uvj}
= (a^v)^{uj}
= (a^v)^{vk+1}
= (a^v)(a^v)^{vk}
$
so
$a^v
=\frac{b^{uvk}}{(a^v)^{vk}}
=(\frac{b^{u}}{a^v})^{vk}
$
or
$a
=(\frac{b^{u}}{a^v})^{k}
$.

For 
$(\frac{b^{u}}{a^v})^{k}$
to be an integer,
$\frac{b^{u}}{a^v}$
must be an integer,
which proves the result for $a$.

Similarly
$a^{uvj}
=b^{uvk}
=(b^u)^{vk}
=(b^u)^{uj-1}
$
so
$b^ua^{uvj}
=(b^u)^{uj}
$
or
$ba^{vj}
=b^{uj}
$
or
$b
=(\frac{b^u}{a^v})^j
$.

Therefore
$r = \frac{b^u}{a^v}$
works.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a^j=b^k$, the exponents in its prime factorization are all multiples of $k$. Suppose $p^i\|a$, then we have that $k|ij$. Since $k$ and $j$ are relatively prime, then $k|i$. This is true for each prime dividing $a$, so $a$ is a $k$th power. A symmetric argument shows that $b$ is a $j$th power.

(The notation $p^i\|a$ means that $p^i|a$ and $p^{i+1}\not| a$.)

Answer (score 0):

*Notation*: for a prime $p$ and a positive integer $n$ let $m_p(n)$ be the greatest integer such that $p^{m_p(n)}\mid n$.

If $a=1$ then $b=1$ and the statement is obvious.

Otherwise, suppose that a prime $p$ divides $a$ and that $s=m_p(a)$.

Then $p^{js}$ divides $b^k$ and $js=m_p(b^k)$. Let $t=m_p(b)$. Then $js=kt$. Since $\gcd(j,k)=1$, $j\mid t$ and $k\mid s$. Say $t=d_1j$ and $s=d_2k$. We get

$$jd_2k=kd_1j$$

Therefore, $d_1=d_2$ (call it $d_p$) and $p^s=(p^{d_p})^k$, $p^t=(p^{d_p})^j$.

Now use this reasoning for every prime factor of $a$. You can define $d_p=m_p(a^j)/k$ for each prime factor of $a$ to get

$$a=\left(\prod_{p\mid a} p^{d_p}\right)^k$$

$$b=\left(\prod_{p\mid a} p^{d_p}\right)^j$$