# If $x^n=y^m$ then are $x$ and $y$ integer powers of some integer $z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y>1$ be positive integers. Suppose there exist positive integers $n,m$ so that $x^n=y^m$. Then is it true there are positive integers $z,a,b$ so that $x=z^a$ and $y=z^b$?

I know that $x,y$ have to have the same prime numbers in their factorization. I also know they have to be rational powers of some $z$. But do they have to be the integer power of another number?

Comment: $n,m$ have not both be zero (which implies neither is zero.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elementary number theory exponent problem (Peter Hackman book)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634224/elementary-number-theory-exponent-problem-peter-hackman-book) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5En%3Dy%5Em%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%3Dz%5Ea%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). Note that if $d=\gcd(m,n)$, then $m=dm_1,n=dn_1,\gcd(m_1,n_1)=1$ and $x^{m}=y^{n}\;\to\;(x^{m_1})^d=(y^{n_1})^d\;\to\;x^{m_1}=y^{n_1}$, so your question is essentially the same as that in the proposed duplicate. ...

Comment: (cont.) You're welcome. FYI, note that another closely related question that was also in the results list is [If a field element is simultaneously an $m$th and $n$th power...](/q/1632412).